# Quartz scheduler not working after running from published folder in .net

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

From vs 2017 it is working find in debug mode , but when published and try to run getting following exception

```
2019-03-24 13:55:45,475 [18792] INFO  Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger.Info(:0) - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
    2019-03-24 13:55:45,487 [18792] INFO  Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger.InfoFormat(:0) - Quartz Scheduler v.2.0.0.100 created.
    2019-03-24 13:55:45,492 [18792] INFO  Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger.Info(:0) - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.0.0.100) 'ServerScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
      Scheduler class: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
      NOT STARTED.
      Currently in standby mode.
      Number of jobs executed: 0
      Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
      Using job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

    2019-03-24 13:55:45,493 [18792] INFO  Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger.Info(:0) - Registering Quartz Job Initialization Plug-in.
    2019-03-24 13:55:45,500 [18792] INFO  Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger.Info(:0) - Scheduler ServerScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
    2019-03-24 13:55:45,501 [18792] INFO  Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger.Info(:0) - Scheduler ServerScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
    2019-03-24 13:55:45,504 [18792] ERROR Jagaha.QuartzServer.QuartzServer.Initialize(:0) - Server initialization failed:Thread has not been started.
    System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread has not been started.
       at System.Threading.Thread.JoinInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
       at System.Threading.Thread.Join()
       at Quartz.QuartzThread.Join()
       at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Shutdown(Boolean waitForJobsToComplete)
       at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate()
       at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
       at Jagaha.QuartzServer.QuartzServer.GetScheduler()
       at Jagaha.QuartzServer.QuartzServer.Initialize()
```

Any suggestion what will be solution to resolve the published version of console application.

Comment: Can you post the initialization code for the scheduler?

Comment: I have manually put reference dlls from build debug folder to publish folder and it has been resolved, thanks

Comment: Sounds for me not like a good solution, but this is your decision.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to manually put reference DLLs from build debug folder to publish folder. While it is an imperfect solution, it resolves the problem